# In characteristic $2$, can a function have a non-zero second derivative?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, field-theory, positive-characteristic

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field with characteristic $2$, and with a non-trivial absolute value. (The simplest example is $\mathbb F_2(T)$, the field of formal rational expressions with coefficients in $\mathbb F_2$. The absolute value of a polynomial is $|p(T)|=2^{-n}\in\mathbb R$, where $p(T)$ has a factor of $T^n$ but not $T^{n+1}$.)

Let $f:\mathbb F\to\mathbb F$ be a function. Limits and derivatives are defined as usual: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$ means that for any real (or rational) $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x\in\mathbb F$ where $0<|x-a|<\delta$, $|f(x)-b|<\varepsilon$. And

$$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$

Is it possible that $f''(a)$ exists in $\mathbb F\setminus\{0\}$?

---

If $f=g\cdot h$ where $g$ and $h$ are twice differentiable, the product rule gives

$$f''=g''h+2g'h'+gh''$$
$$=g''h+gh''.$$

If $f=g\circ h$, the chain rule gives

$$f''=(g''\circ h)\cdot h'^2+(g'\circ h)\cdot h''.$$

Any polynomial function $p(x)=\sum a_nx^n$ has second derivative $p''(x)=\sum a_nn(n-1)x^{n-2}=0$ because $n(n-1)$ is always even. The derivatives of the reciprocal $f(x)=1/x$ are $f'(x)=-1/x^2$ and $f''(x)=2/x^3=0$. It follows from the above properties that any rational function $f(x)=p(x)/q(x)$ also has $f''(x)=0$. The square root function satisfies $f(x)^2-x=0$; differentiating this gives $-1=0$, so it must not be differentiable. I'm not sure about general algebraic functions.

I thought of using the symmetric second derivative formula, but I don't think it's valid:

$$f''(a)\overset?=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(a+x)-2f(a)+f(a-x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{0}{x^2}$$

Well, let's apply the definition directly and see what happens:

$$f''(a)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(a+x)-f'(a)}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(a+x+y)-f(a+x)}{y}-\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(a+y)-f(a)}{y}}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(a+x+y)-f(a+x)-f(a+y)+f(a)}{xy}$$

We can't take $y=x$ here to get $f''=0$, because it's not a single limit $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ but two nested limits.

An equivalent description of differentiability is that there's some continuous function $h$ with $h(0)=0$ such that

$$f(a+x)=f(a)+xf'(a)+xh(x).$$

So the second derivative is

$$f''(a)=\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}\frac{(x+y)h(x+y)-xh(x)-yh(y)}{xy}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}\left(\frac{h(x+y)-h(x)}{y}+\frac{h(x+y)-h(y)}{x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\lim_{y\to0}\frac{h(x+y)-h(x)}{y}+\frac{h(x)}{x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\left(h'(x)+\frac{h(x)}{x}\right).$$

Note that all of these limits must exist, in order for $f''(a)$ to exist. But we can't simplify this further, since $h'$ may be discontinuous or undefined at $0$.

---

We may even consider the special case where $f$ has a $2$nd-order Peano derivative: there's some continuous function $g$ with $g(0)=0$ such that

$$f(a+x)=f(a)+xf'(a)+x^2f^\ddagger(a)+x^2g(x).$$

Then the second derivative is

$$f''(a)=2f^\ddagger(a)+\lim_{x\to0}xg'(x).$$

Is it possible that this limit exists in $\mathbb F\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: If I have an example of a topological ring (but not field) of pure characteristic 2, and a function on it with nonzero second derivative, would that be sufficiently close to what you're asking for?  (Then, I think taking the quotient field of that topological ring might also give an example, but I'm not as sure about that.)

Comment: No, let's focus on fields here. You could ask-answer a separate post about general topological rings. I'm not sure if I should allow general topological fields, without absolute values. (Apparently they exist: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311047/ostrowskis-theorem-for-topological-rings)

Comment: Hmm, OK.  As it happens, though, I realized that my example is very much not an integral domain; so it wouldn't be possible to take the quotient field anyway.